# Angular convert $http.post to XHR

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to do some upload and get so progress feedback.

What i used to do (before to watch for progress):

```
$http.post(BASE_URL, formData, {
withCredentials: true,
transformRequest: angular.identity,
params: {'context': context}
})
```

I tried to convert to:

```
var xhrObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrObj.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressFunction, false);
xhrObj.open("POST", BASE_URL, true);
xhrObj.withCredentials = true;
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", fileItem.file.type);
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("X_FILE_NAME", fileItem.file.name);
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Expires", "0");
//xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
xhrObj.send(fd);
```

But it seems credentials are not passed, how should i do ?

Comment: are sure about `fd` has data?

Comment: yes, i've just created if with the file (and when i send the XHR), i got content in request payload

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Not really, i see: (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in chrome status of the http request. No authentication (cookies...) are given by browser. (as if withCredentials was not understood)

Comment: It seems we can do it thanks to eventHandlers and keep original $http.post, gonna try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so no need to do it manually !

Since angular 1.5.4 (and some bugfixes in 1.5.5), you can use eventHandlers and uploadEventHandlers.

See: https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/api/ng/service/$http

So simply do that:

```
$http.post(BASE_URL, formData, {
withCredentials: true,
transformRequest: angular.identity,
params: {'context': context},
uploadEventHandlers: {
  progress: function(event) {//Add whatever you want to do}
}
})
```